# how to maximum value of a column in sql in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is my model function

```
    public function bids_info($id){
          $this->db->select_max('bid_amount');
  $this->db->where('product_id', $id);
  $result = $this->db->get('wc_bids');

  $this->db->select('*')->select('wc_bids.id, wc_seller_products.id as p_id')
    ->from('wc_bids')
    ->join('wc_buyer', 'wc_bids.buyer_id = wc_buyer.id', 'LEFT')
    ->join('wc_seller_products', 'wc_bids.product_id = wc_seller_products.id', 'LEFT')
    ->where('wc_bids.bid_amount',$result);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    }
```

and i have table wc_bids like this [image: wc_bids table image]

i want to fetch maximum bid_amount where my product_id is 22
as in model $id =22.... pls help me the proper query... thanks in advance

Comment: Use select_max() - http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Comment: i dont know why select_max not working fr me

Comment: How u use it ? add it to question

Comment: What give you var_dump($result); ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your Model as this.

```
public function bids_info($id)
{
    $this->db->select_max('bid_amount');
    $this->db->where('product_id', $id);
    $result = $this->db->get('wc_bids')->row(); // * Added ->row()

    $bid_amount = $result['bid_amount']; // * Added this.

    $this->db->select('*')->select('wc_bids.id, wc_seller_products.id as p_id')
             ->from('wc_bids')
             ->join('wc_buyer', 'wc_bids.buyer_id = wc_buyer.id', 'LEFT')
             ->join('wc_seller_products', 'wc_bids.product_id = wc_seller_products.id', 'LEFT')
             ->where('wc_bids.bid_amount', $bid_amount); // * Added $bid_amount instead of $result;
    $query = $this->db->get();
}
```